# HTML 5 - Web Sockets on Browser close

Tags: html, websocket

How does a Server know to close a Web Socket connection in HTML5 on below scenarios and other cases.

1. Browser closed abruptly
2. Browser Refresh(A new Socket connection creation or still it will use existing Connection)
3. System abrupt power off

Comment: Check out Keep alive. http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html

Answer (score 1):

In case the client quits without being able to notify the server, the basic characteristics of the TCP implementation define the behavior.

As long as your application (and host system itself) do not attempt to send any data over this broken connection, the host will not realize that something is wrong. Hence, the connection could stay 'open' for a long while and allocate resources, from the server's point of view.

However, in the moment data is attempted to be sent to the remote end, the remote end will not acknowledge the retrieval and TCP retransmission comes into play. It involves a certain number of repetitions and used timeouts. The exact parameters depend on the implementation (operating system in use). When the retransmission finally fails, the TCP connection is closed and resources are freed on the server side. So you can

- rely on the fact that at some point your application might want to write to the missing remote end and while doing so trigger the detection of the dead connection **or**
- detect missing remote ends yourself by using something like pings on the application level **or**
- use something like pings on the operating system level, via TCP keepalive techniques.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest part of your question is the browser refresh part. IE,FF and Chrome will close the opened connection and open a new one. I guess, that any other browser will do the same.

Point 1 and 3 i can only guess: If the client can still close the tcp connection cleanly, the server will  immediately recognize that the connection has been closed. If you are using tomcat, the onClose method of the MessageInbound instance will be called.

If the client could not close the tcp connection cleanly, the server will wait for some kind of timeout. The server will definitely timeout fast when it tries to write something to the socket. You could implement a heartbeat mechanism to do this. Websockets seem to have the option of an automatic heartbeat but not all browsers and servers seem to support it.

Answer (score 0):

If a user closes a browser tab with an opened web socket, the server will not know this one has been closed right away. However, as Jan-Philip says, if you attempt to write the operation will fail and using the error given you know the current state for the connection.

For example, when using the ws lib for nodejs, if you try to send data to a closed websocket an exception will be thrown, saying something like [Error: not opened]. Their you know the connection no longer exists and you can do any cleanup needed.